# Апплоуд в цикле

Tags: ajax, php, upload

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать так что бы этот код выполнялся в цикле ? Облазил довольно много чего но решил задать вам, код нужно вогнать в цикл не изменяя проверки и сжатие. Все это делается для апплоуда, тк на данный момент этот код загружает всего лишь одну фотографию ajax ом а нужно две и более ... Заранее Спасибо!

```
    $path = "uploads/";
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif","JPG","JPEG","jpeg");
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
 {
  $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
  $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];
  if(strlen($name))
         {
    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
        {
        if ($size < MAX_SIZE*1024)
            {
            $actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;

            $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                {
                $command=mysql_query("Insert into uploads(image_name) values ('$actual_image_name')");
                $query=mysql_query("Select upload_id,image_name from uploads where image_name='$actual_image_name'");
                $result=mysql_fetch_array($query);
                $id=$result['upload_id'];

                echo "<img src='uploads/".$actual_image_name."' class='preview' id='$id'>";         
                    }
```

Comment: Темы плодить не нужно. Тем более, что [предыдущий вопрос](http://hashcode.ru/questions/223255/php-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC) никто не закрыл.

Comment: окей, я просто думал что кто то подскажет как это в цикл загнать